# Subnets not ping eachother on strongswa vpn tunnel

Tags: vpn, ping, iproute, tunneling, strongswan

AOA, I have two clients one remote and other is local but both on same LAN i.e (192.168.137.0/24), while the UBuntu servers in which strongswan is implemented are connected to each other with ethernet cable having port addresses 10.10.3.10 and 10.10.3.11 respectively, while connected to devices with port addresses 192.168.137.10 and 11 respectively.

But when tunnel is established the devices ping each other but the subnets cant.

Should I have to add some routes.
Config:

**Client1(192.168.137.19)-----(192.168.137.10)Device1(10.10.3.10)=====(10.10.3.11)Device2(192.168.137.11)-------Client2(192.168.137.20)**

**ipsec.conf Device1**

```
'config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
    strictcrlpolicy=no
conn %default
conn TUFAAN
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=10.10.3.10
    leftsubnet=192.168.137.0/24
    right=10.10.3.11
    rightsubnet=192.168.137.0/24
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart'
```

**ipsec.conf Device2**

```
'config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
    strictcrlpolicy=no
conn %default
conn TUFAAN
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=10.10.3.11
    leftsubnet=192.168.137.0/24
    right=10.10.3.10
    rightsubnet=192.168.137.0/24
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **leftsubnets** and your **rightsubnets** are the same subnet; how is a packet supposed to know where to go? When a device on one subnet (in this case it really doesn't matter which) tries to ping 192.168.137.8, why would it travel across the VPN to do that rather than remain in it's own collision domain?

Meanwhile, the actual IP addresses of the Strongswan VPN servers are much less confusing; they are both members of the same collision domain and have unique IP addresses within that domain, i.e., 10.10.3.10 and 11.

Comment: Thanks God somebody replied. I have changed leftsubnet to 192.168.138.0/24 and add some routes on both clients. Now the clients ping each other, but the problem is that when I check packets from 192.168.137.19-----192.168.138.20 are encrypted through wireshark, then they are transmitted with ICMP protocol. Are the packets really encrypted or not. I can give you routes details if you want

Comment: Wireshark won't see the encryption if wire shark is on one of those networks. The packets are only encrypted from outside views, by the VPN server; anything on the left or right subnet only sees unencrypted packets. Also please mark this as the answer since it solved your problem.

Comment: I have one last query that if I want to establish VPN Tunnel between two clients on same network, then what changes I have to made in ipsec.conf file i.e if both subnets behind both gateway servers are on same network then how would I buld vpn tunnel in that case.

Comment: You should mark this question as ***answered*** if it has helped you. Any other questions should be made in a new post

Comment: But to answer your second question; I haven't been able to make that work, so I'm not sure if it can be done. Perhaps there is a way, but not any that I can think of. I suppose you could make static routes, but it seems that it would be unreliable if it worked at all.